# Is it possible to add badge won into "about me"?

Tags: support, badges, profile-page

I wanted to know if it is possible to add a badge earned in the presentation of his profile.

Like :

[image]

Comment: AFAIK not, But you could do something like this user did: https://stackoverflow.com/users/100297/martijn-pieters at the bottom of his profile textbox.

Comment: Teaser: there are changes coming soon to the profile/activity pages (to be here first, to get community feedback)...